# use locale - question

Tags: perl, locale, pragma

When I set my `locale` to `it_IT.UTF-8` (export LC_ALL=it_IT.UTF-8) and run this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

say strftime "%A %B %e %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime;
```

I get this output:

```
martedì marzo 15 08:50:07 2011
```

but reading this (from [The-use-locale-pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#The-use-locale-pragma) ):

`By default, Perl ignores the current locale. 
The use locale pragma tells Perl to use the current locale for some operations:
...
The POSIX date formatting function (strftime()) uses LC_TIME .`

why does my locale-setting have an influence on the strftime-output without the use of the `locale` pragma?

Comment: It seems that `POSIX` and locales is just a dark corner of Perl. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214418/is-locale-setting-global-in-perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`POSIX::strftime` is a thin wrapper around the real `strftime` C function call in `time.h` which uses the current locale.  Perl doesn't go through the effort to make it conform.

[DateTime has a strftime equivalent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime#strftime_Patterns) implemented in Perl that will conform to Perl's locale pragma.